# How to find IPA file through ApplicationLoader

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

**I work in Visual Studio for Windows.** For building iOS app VS use Mac as build server. After building process **I have IPA file at the windows host**.

Than I need to upload it through ApplicationLoader. But ApplicationLoader is running on Mac and how can it access to windows host ipa? 
The Visual Stuiod has command 'Show IPA file on build server' and when I use it I see finder is opened at someplace at Mac. But what is this place?
I start ApplicationLoader and try to find this IPA file without success.

1. Where is it? As workaround I copied (drag&drop) ipa file from this unknown folder to Mac desktop and selected the file from there.
2. When I upload ipa to iTunesConnect I don't see loaded symbols! Why the symbols isn't loaded?

And the last. I heard about fastlane that it prefer way to upload symbols to Crashlytics. So how can it worked as project files placed in Windows host?

Comment: you can find build from product folder with .app extension after that this .app file drag to itunes under application. after complete that process click on your application icon and select show in finder option it will be show your ipa.

Answer (score 2):

You can't find ipa file after archive because it will not create ipa.

You need to create file manually .

Follow this steps to create .ipa

1. Right click on recent archive file in organisation and select show in finder option.
2. After you will .xcarchive file.
3. Right click on that file an select Show Package and content option.
4. Under Product folder. you can find .app file.
5. Drag .app file to application section in itunes after completion of process right click on icon and select show in finder option.
6. That's your ipa File .

**Second solution**

1. Build your project with production certificate .
2. After Build under product folder you can see .app file and show it in finder .
3. Follow to 5 and 6 from above solution.

Comment: Do you note that I working in Visual Studio in Windows?

Comment: you can do this visual studio also. replace finder with your computer folder.

Comment: or see this . https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10746/how-to-build-an-adhoc-ipa-file-for-an-ios-app-in-visual-studio-2012-asked-and-answered

Comment: where are project files been placed in Mac? The project files are placed on Windows only, isn't are?

Answer (score -1):

You need to [archive](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing_to_the_app_store/#Building_and_Submitting_the_Distributable) .ipa, not just build for release.

Comment: "The Xamarin plugin for Visual Studio does not currently support the Archiving workflow for publishing iOS applications to the App Store. As a result, you have upload an IPA created via the Build Ad hoc IPA command, which is described below." I have .ipa. That is not the question.

Comment: @AlexeySubbota yes, by bad. The instruction say that you need to build with release provisioning, however, the instruction is giving for Ah-Hoc, are you building with correct one? "This section describes building an IPA, similar to the workflow when using Ad Hoc or Enterprise Distribution. However, it will be signed using the App Store provisioning profile that was created above."

Comment: You mean that I have the wrong .ipa? I can not understand where you are driving. Which question do you answer?

Comment: In some kind. Your .ipa MUST be signed with a correct provision (release one) to be able to make it into iTunesConnect via Application Loader. Please start with checking certificates :)

Comment: I copied ipa to the Mac desktop and successful loaded it to iTunesConnect. And I can to download the app from TestFlight. But! I cannot see symbols loaded to TestFlyght. It's a pity that I cannot show to you the screenshots what I mean. Is the certificates play any role for it?

Comment: @AlexeySubbota now I see your struggle. I checked, looks like there is no info on how to upload dSYM for TestFlight using Xamarin Windows Plugin, you need to have Xamarin Mac. All that I suggest now - save that dSYM file, you will be able to symbolicate crashes with it later on your local machine.